# How to delete data with date value + time

Tags: mysql

I want to delete data between 'change_slot' and ('change_slot' + 2min) WHERE type = ' crash', 'pilot_death', or 'eject'

```
DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent 
WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = 'crash'  
OR pe_LogEvent_type = 'pilot_death' 
OR pe_LogEvent_type = 'eject' 
AND pe_LogEvent_datetime IN??? pe_LogEvent_type = 'change_slot'  
BETWEEN ('change_slot datetime') AND (DATE_ADD('change_slot datetime', INTERVAL 120)))
```

Visual SQL DB Image with annotation of what I am trying to accomplish.:
[image: Visual SQL DB Image with annotation of what I am trying to accomplish.]

I have another issue now, I'm trying to think of a way to solve this one as well. I was trying to use maybe a 'for each' iterative statement to filter only 1 pilotname at a time maybe? How would you go about solving this?

[Problem: different pilot change_slot and causes current pilot's death not to count now ... I need to only have same pilot change_slot within 2 min pilot_death, crash, or eject does not count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5C6o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent
WHERE pe_LogEvent_datetime BETWEEN 
(SELECT pe_LogEvent_datetime FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = 'change_slot' ORDER BY pe_LogEvent_datetime DESC LIMIT 1) 
AND (SELECT pe_LogEvent_datetime + INTERVAL 2 MINUTES FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = 'change_slot' ORDER BY pe_LogEvent_datetime DESC LIMIT 1) 
AND pe_LogEvent_type IN ('crash', 'pilot_death', 'eject')
```

Somethink like this?

EDIT:

According to your comments below this answer, propably you want something like this, but i am not sure but if not, propably you could change this SQL at your own.

For such non-obvious queries i always use the CTE. I love it because you could use it to 'separate' your logic to simplest 'steps'. Then it's looks simple and easy to see what going on (At least for me) instead of one big query from which it is not so easy to deduce what is happening and is more difficult to edit/read.

First you could use the CTE to get all 'change_slot' type events with dates:

```
WITH change_slots_dates AS (
    SELECT 
        pe_LogEvent_datetime AS date_start,
        pe_LogEvent_datetime + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AS end_time
    FROM pe_LogEvent 
    WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = 'change_slot'
)
```

then another CTE to get IDs between this dates (Remember that your's CTE need to be separate by `,` sign:

```
rows_to_delete AS (
    SELECT 
        pe.pe_LogEvent_id AS id
    FROM pe_LogEvent AS pe
        INNER JOIN change_slots_dates AS csd ON (pe.pe_LogEvent_datetime  BETWEEN csd.date_start AND csd.end_time)
    WHERE pe.pe_LogEvent_type IN ('crash', 'pilot_death', 'eject')
)
```

after that you can finally delete this entities:

```
DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_id IN (SELECT id FROM rows_to_delete);
```

Notice that this is a one SQL query and you cannot use this as 3 queries. So all seems to be like this:

```
WITH change_slots_dates AS (
    SELECT 
        pe_LogEvent_datetime AS date_start,
        pe_LogEvent_datetime + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AS end_time
    FROM pe_LogEvent 
    WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = 'change_slot'
),
rows_to_delete AS (
    SELECT 
        pe.pe_LogEvent_id AS id
    FROM pe_LogEvent AS pe
        INNER JOIN change_slots_dates AS csd ON (pe.pe_LogEvent_datetime  BETWEEN csd.date_start AND csd.end_time)
    WHERE pe.pe_LogEvent_type IN ('crash', 'pilot_death', 'eject')
)
DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_id IN (SELECT id FROM rows_to_delete);
```

I hope it will be finally more helpfull.

Comment: AWESOME that's it! (just had to change MINUTES to MINUTE)
1 issue, this is for only 1 iteration.

How do I do for each of the 'change_slot' entries?
When I take away the 'DESC LIMIT 1' ... then I get an error saying 
"Error updating record: Subquery returns more than 1 row" 
I guess I have to add the 'for each' statement and iterate through it somehow. 
I'll keep trying stuff, any help would be appreciated, thanks for the work so far resolved most of the issue!

Comment: How do I iterate through each instance For each row that includes 'change_slot' ?

Comment: Check the answer again. I edited it based on your comments.

Comment: This is wonderfully helpful. I will not be able to do this straight off bc in mysqli php you can't add a delete WITH a query .. however ... I CAN make 2 tables and then use those to delete from 2 real tables =) . The code is written beautifully. When I venture into SQL by itself ... this CTE example will be massively helpful to me as a sort of structure on how it works. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: IT WORKS! made one table and then inserted your 2nd 'rows_to_delete' code into the delete from statement. Thank you so much, this was a learning experience for me on how to use CTE (FOR ONLY SQL CODE). Much appreciated. =)

Comment: New Problem: different pilot change_slot and causes current pilot's death not to count now ... I need to only have same pilot change_slot within 2 min pilot_death, crash, or eject does not count. I'm trying to think of a way to solve this one as well. I was trying to use maybe a 'for each' iterative statement to filter only 1 pilotname at a time maybe? How would you go about solving this?

Comment: If you'd like I can put up another question post so that you can get more reputation points if you'd like. Just let me know.

Comment: I put an image of the data up above as a more descriptive way of purposing the question. I thought up different ways and tried a few things, still can't crack it though.

Comment: Actually I think i might have it here.

Comment: Yup finished it =) still strange output for a different reason, output result verified =) thanks so much again!

Comment: For the future: don't change your post to a different question, because someone might find it and the answer won't fit it, which may be confuse. It's better if one post correspond to one problem. According to https://stackoverflow.com/tour "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions". Stack isn't discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. Only question, and answers. If we collect all the problems in one post, it will be difficult to read them, not to mention finding the answer. On your example you had 1 problem and it has been solved, then you have another, so put another question.